# Excessive memory consumption in empty Win32 C++ app

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

My humble concern is the following:

Presets:

1. Purchase Windows 10, and install it
2. Download and install Visual Studio 2017, Community, version 15.2
3. Configure it for C++
4. Create a new C++ project, Win32 app with basic settings (without ATL, non-console)
5. Build and debug run (see how an empty window appears)
6. Observe process memory (within VS2017 or other tool)

My observations:

The executable itself is (150 kB). App itself - when running - starts by taking 2 MB of memory. Without toughing it, the memory consumption changes; sometimes grows sometimes decreases (my max is now 3 MB after few minutes to 30 minutes observation perion). You can even minimize it at start and just observe the memory consumption either using Visual Studio or performance monitor. I cannot see anything on the I/O bytes, cannot be sure though.

My questions are:

1. What is taking so much memory?
2. Why the memory usage is varying over the time without user interactions?

Thanks!

Comment: I waste a couple of megabytes every time I sneeze, so that's nothing that I think I would worry about. Any process incurs some overhead just for starting up. `std::cin`, `std::cout`, and other objects don't exactly grow on trees. Plus, on MS-Windows the process the additional bloat of having to support an open window. That doesn't exactly cost zero bytes, either.

Comment: Compared to the 751MBs chrome is using right now, no, it's not that much.

Comment: Did you compile using `release` or `debug`?

Comment: Build using the release setting. It will remove unnecessary debug codes for you which you basically don't need for an empty app

Comment: Default stack size is about 1Mb

Comment: VS creates a bunch of icons for default projects. I think you can trim the exe file size by half if you remove those. But it's recommended to have those.

Comment: I used `debug`, `release` did affect a little to the consumption but seems that is the window management as Sami suggested that takes the memory. With `release` empty console app, the initial working set is 500 kb. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Most (all?) of the window management structures are stored in kernel space and do not contribute to your application's working set. The system however creates additional threads in your process, with the default stack size being 1 MB. The CRT startup code needs memory to run, the heap manager grabs memory up front, executable images are mapped into the address space, etc. But since you never asked about what occupies that memory, my proposed answer didn't address that. As such, it is no more helpful than the questions you asked allows it to be.

Comment: @IInspectable I am sorry I formatted my questions very badly but maybe they are now more to the point. Already, there have been good suggestions so they are not totally unanswered. Still, 2MB is a HUGE amount of memory. As you said even the window mgmt is done outside of the process, the original mystery still stays.

Comment: Don't change the question after you have received an answer, thereby invalidating the answer. If you have a new question, use the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani There is only one icon file and it is 46 kb.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the memory usage of 3 MB of an empty app really OK for you?

Yes, that is ok for me.

> If it is, could you explain to me why it is so?

Because I have [4GB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912.aspx) or [several terabytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384271.aspx) of virtual address space to spare.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If that were the case, why ask the first question then?

Comment: After rereading the question, I think your interpretation is correct. I'll withdraw the comment.